# Is it possible to script ISIS Mapper?

Tags: mapping

I am working on a large modelling and mapping project that will require the processing of significant numbers of 1d models through [ISIS Mapper](http://help.floodmodeller.com/isis/mergedProjects/ISIS%20MAPPER/whnjs.htm).

Has anyone had any experience of scripting tools in ISIS mapper to batch process the extraction of model results or the interpolation of 1D results?

A google search and hunt through the information provided by Halcrow doesn't provide any suggestions.

Comment: Please help Ed and I, because I have the same problem. I have only basic knowledge when it comes to python and have to write script that retrieves the integrated-ISIS IGP network topology from a Cisco, Juniper and Alcatel router and stores the topology in an abstract graph format(such as graphml). The command to get this information on Cisco might be "show isis database verbose"